# Using Scrapy to scrape a site that uses XMLHttpRequests to load its content

Tags: python, json, ajax, scrapy

The site I am attempting to scrape (in the browser) returns 50 job titles at a time. When I attempt to use scrapy to return all job titles, it will only scrape 20 of them.

Link to the webpage:
https://recruiting.ultipro.com/COM1038/JobBoard/d22da326-8928-4fbc-8b3b-99b6db355d5d/?q=&o=postedDateDesc

Once I went to this page I realized that the content was being rendered dynamically so I right clicked and inspected the page and reloaded it with the XHR >  Network tab open in Dev Tools. It shows two files

1. GetFilters
2. LoadOpportunities

'LoadOpportunities' seemed to be promising so I looked at the "Response" under the XHR tab and it has returned what seems to be a JSON file containing all the information I could ever want. I used CTRL-f to search for "Title" and found 50 occurrences. Perfect!

So then to test it. I opened up Scrapy Shell and viewed the page that had returned the JSON:

https://recruiting.ultipro.com/COM1038/JobBoard/d22da326-8928-4fbc-8b3b-99b6db355d5d/JobBoardView/LoadOpportunities

When you open up this page in a browser, it only returns 20 of (the currently) 54 job openings. I had first discovered this when I had used the json package and scrapy shell to scrape the page.

When you look at the "Preview" tab in the browser using the first link I had posted under the "LoadOpportunities' file, you can see that it has up to 50 values beneath the 'opportunities' key. I am trying to scrape the value 'Title' from each of those.

I also created a scraper that does the same thing using the HTML response but its not particularly useful. It isn't getting the job done since it's not actually interacting with the dynamic webpage, just the partial JSON file that the initial page is connected to.

```
import scrapy, re, json, requests
from ..items import MetroSouthItems

class MetroSouth(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "metrosouth"
    start_urls = [
    'https://recruiting.ultipro.com/COM1038/JobBoard/d22da326-8928-4fbc-8b3b-99b6db355d5d/JobBoardView/LoadOpportunities',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        html_res = response.body
        decoded_res = str(html_res,"utf-8")
        json_file = open("metrosouth.json", "w")
        json_file.write(decoded_res)
        with open("metrosouth.json") as json_data:
            data = json.load(json_data)
            items = MetroSouthItems()
            for i in range(len(data["opportunities"])):
                items["job_title"] = data["opportunities"][i]["Title"]
                print(i)
                yield items
```

I would like to get all jobs that are available scraped and then at some point shovel those off to a database/ possibly have the spider re-run every morning so that I can keep track of new listings. Right now I have it overwrite a JSON file with the new listings.

If anyone has any tips or guidance for moving forward I would greatly appreciate it. I have a feeling that it has something to do with Javascript since it does say that "LoadOpportunities" is initiated by a jslib but I do not have much experience with javascript and don't really know what all that means.

Answer (score 2):

In page originally they make POST-request with some additional payload. We can reproduce it with something like this:

```
import scrapy, json


class MetroSouth(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "metrosouth"
    search_url = url = 'https://recruiting.ultipro.com/COM1038/JobBoard/d22da326-8928-4fbc-8b3b-99b6db355d5d/JobBoardView/LoadOpportunities'

    def start_requests(self):
        payload = """{"opportunitySearch":{"Top":100,"Skip":0,"QueryString":"","OrderBy":[{"Value":"postedDateDesc","PropertyName":"PostedDate","Ascending":false}],"Filters":[{"t":"TermsSearchFilterDto","fieldName":4,"extra":null,"values":[]},{"t":"TermsSearchFilterDto","fieldName":5,"extra":null,"values":[]},{"t":"TermsSearchFilterDto","fieldName":6,"extra":null,"values":[]}]},"matchCriteria":{"PreferredJobs":[],"Educations":[],"LicenseAndCertifications":[],"Skills":[],"hasNoLicenses":false,"SkippedSkills":[]}}"""
        yield scrapy.Request(self.search_url, method='POST', body=payload)

    def parse(self, response):
        j = json.loads(response.text)
        print '======'
        for i, row in enumerate(j.get('opportunities')):
            print i, ' - ', row.get('Title')
        print '======'
```

Check parameter `Top` in payload. Originally it is set to 50 and request to page gives us 20 records. But I've increased it to 100 and now I get all 54 records.
Hope it will help.

Comment: I haven't tried it for myself yet but I will take your word for it. Thank you so much!

I did try to send along a payload in some separate code but I couldn't get it to work. This may sound like a dumb question but how can you tell when a page requires a payload or some other kind of parameters @vezunchik ?

Comment: The new code didn't work for me. I didn't copy and paste your code but I did adjust it to go along with ypour solution. I will add an updated version of my code above for review. Let me know if you see anything that I did wrong.